# Specific query error - SQLite Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

my problem is with very specific query. My SQLite datbase is only 1 table with 11 entries. It creates just fine, but upon execution of this piece of code it crashes. When I change the query to simply:

```
SELECT * FROM Items
```

Then it works fine, but I need more narrow results, therefore I modify with the "WHERE" clause. But then it crashes and the application stops. If I comment out the `Cursor...` it runs fine.

```
public int findPictureNumber(String itemtitle) {
        String query = "SELECT nr_of_pics FROM Items WHERE ItemTitle =  \"" + itemtitle + "\"";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);



  ...
        }
```

Where is the error? I can't seem to find it even after narrowing it down to those lines of code.

EDIT:
This is  a method for adding an item to a database.

```
public void newItemFuro () {
   MyDBHandler dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);

            String title = "Furo";
            String author = "Fernando Brizio";//í
            String category = "Decoracao";//çã
            int date = 2012;
            String type = "Taca";//ç
            String country = "Portugal";
            String colour = "Castanho/Cortica";//ç
            String material = "Castanho/Cortica";//ç
            boolean isFavourite = false;
            String imgres = "furoo";
            int nr_of_pics = 3;
   Item item = new Item(title, author, category, date, type, country, colour, material, isFavourite, imgres, nr_of_pics);
   dbHandler.addItem(item);
```

}

```
//helper for types
public static final String VARCHAR_TYPE = " VARCHAR(50)";
public static final String BOOL_TYPE = " BOOLEAN";
public static final String INT_TYPE = " INTEGER";
```

Here it creates the table:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEMS + 
            "("
                 + COLUMN_ENTRY_ID      + INT_TYPE +" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," 
                 + COLUMN_TITLE         + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_AUTHOR        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_CATEGORY      + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_DATE          + INT_TYPE      + ","
                 + COLUMN_TYPE          + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_COUNTRY       + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_COLOUR        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_MATERIAL      + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_FAVOURITE     + BOOL_TYPE     + ","
                 + COLUMN_IMGRES        + VARCHAR_TYPE  + ","
                 + COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_PICS + INT_TYPE + 
            ")";
      db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEMS_TABLE);
}
```

Adding item:

```
public void addItem(Item item) {

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_TITLE, item.getItemTitle());
    values.put(COLUMN_AUTHOR, item.getAuthor());
    values.put(COLUMN_CATEGORY, item.getCategory());
    values.put(COLUMN_DATE, item.getDate());
    values.put(COLUMN_TYPE, item.getType());
    values.put(COLUMN_COUNTRY, item.getCountry());
    values.put(COLUMN_COLOUR, item.getColour());
    values.put(COLUMN_MATERIAL, item.getMaterial());
    values.put(COLUMN_FAVOURITE, item.getFavourite());
    values.put(COLUMN_IMGRES, item.getImgres());
    values.put(COLUMN_NUMBER_OF_PICS, item.getNumberOfPics());

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);
    db.close();

}
```

Here full function for searching nr_of_pics:

```
public int findPictureNumber(String itemtitle) {
    String query = "SELECT nr_of_pics FROM Items WHERE ItemTitle =  '" + itemtitle + "'";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);


    int PicsNumber=0;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        PicsNumber=Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.close();
        return PicsNumber;
    } else {
        //wtf?
    }
        db.close();
        return 0;
}
```

And the errors say as follows:

```
(1) table Items has no column named imgres

 Error inserting colour=Castanho/Cortiça author=Fernando Brízio
 imgres=furo category=Decoração title=Furo type=Taça date=2012
 nr_of_pics=3 material=Castanho/Cortiça is_favourite=false
 country=Portugal



android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table Items has no column named imgres (code 1): , while 
 compiling: INSERT INTO
 Items(colour,author,imgres,category,title,type,date,nr_of_pics,material,is_favourite,country)
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not give any exception but I think you have error in your SQL. You need to use ' instead of ".

Change your query as below.

```
String query = "SELECT nr_of_pics FROM Items WHERE ItemTitle =  '" + itemtitle + "'";
```

Comment: Tried it, does not change anything.

Comment: What is your exception?

Comment: Also, I have no idea where to get exceptions from in Eclipse, I'm a huge beginner.

Comment: Found it:
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity`

Comment: Add full stack trace to your question.

Comment: One second, I found full strace and it says something helpful, trying to fix it myself.

Comment: Okay, adding it, can't fix it.

Comment: Done, apparently it says it can't find the column named imgres(which is short for image resource, which is why it's a string type), but everywhere else there is this imgres. Is there a possibility that SQLite can't handle tables with 12 columns? Doesn't sound plausible to me.

Comment: You have completely changed your question. Also you did not include full stack trace yet. At which line your exception is thrown?

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to provide only the relevant parts since I cannt seem to find a way to copy it all at once. The line which gives me the error is: `db.insert(TABLE_ITEMS, null, values);` Here. in AddItem

Comment: Please don't leave me!

Comment: Use your SELECT * FROM Items query to see that if your table really contains necessary columns.

Comment: Alright, now I know that it does not create the new column, it only creates the last version, which are some placeholder rows and there are less columns - it does not create the new table - there seems to be the problem with creating the table.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the create table statement?

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that you don't have any column that named "imgres"!
You should modify your query 
"INSERT INTO Items(colour,author,imgres,category,title,type,date,nr_of_pics,material,is_favourite,country)
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"